# Display notification on target page after redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect, notifications

Let's say I have a form on the `add-project.html` page. After the request is done, I redirect the user back to the main `index.html` page.

What I want to do is to display a notification on `index.html` **only** when the user has successfully submitted the form.

I am using this plug-in for the notification : http://redeyeoperations.com/plugins/Notify/

For now, I am using a temporary solution which shows a notification on `add-project.html` when the form has been submitted and then redirects to the main `index.html` page after a `setTimeout` but I don't like it, it's quite dirty.

```
$('#printForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'add-project.php',
        data: $('#printForm').serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            if(result == '1') {
                // Success
                $.notify.basic('Congratulations, your projet has been saved correctly', {
                    occupySpace : true,
                    close : true,
                    autoClose: 5000
                });

                setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location.href = '../index.html';
                }, 2000);
            }
            else {
                // Error
                $.notify.error('Oops, something went wrong ! Make sure you filled all the necessary fields', {
                    occupySpace : true,
                    close : true,
                    autoClose: 5000
                });
            }
        }
    });         
});
```

Is there a clean way to show a notification on the target page after redirect?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why you not try to using ajaxLoad ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

index.html needs some way to know that the form was sent. You could do it by using an url parameter or hash and reading it with js.

```
//after submit
window.location.href = '../index.html#success';

//in index.html
if(window.location.hash == '#success')
{
    //show the notification
}
```

Comment: @Thomas, every reload of page will show notification. Is there way to show this notification just once?

Comment: Thanks so much, this was exactly what I needed in my app! :)

Comment: @Bagdat I know it's a little late.. but you can empty the hash after displaying the notification. And I think that will work.

Comment: @Thomas, yeap, it is a little late) Nevertheless, thank you for your answer!